# Cannot Start Windows Process Activation Service On Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, services, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I have searched high and low and can't figure this one out.
I made a new VM on which Windows Server 2019 Standard was installed.

If WAS is started from Services it gives the following error:
*Error 50: The Request is not supported*
Dependencies  *Remote Procedure Call --> DCOM Server Process Launcher & RPC Endpoint Mapper* are working though.

In Server Manager Events WAS fails and the IDs are 5005,5036,5172.
ID 5172 states *WAS encountered an error trying to read configuration data from file " \?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config,' line number 1073 The error message is: The configuration section system.web cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration. The data field contains the error number *

I am sure these are related but World Wide Web Publishing Service isn't running either.
It gives the following error:
*Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start*

Server config pictures attached.

In IIS App Pool --> Basic Setting --> Changed Managed Pipeline mode from Basic to Integerated, .Net Clr Version v4.30319

When application is started in the App Pool it states *It cannot be started unless WAS is running*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where exactly did you get the ISO?

Comment: I dont know....it is in a folder. We use it to create VMs for testing purposes. I checked another VM and all these services are running on it. I am assuming it was made from the same ISO

Comment: You should confirm that is the case. What you describe could be explained by using a bad ISO for the edition your attempting to install.

Comment: So, you have a valid license? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2019 Go here and download the ISO or VHD, then activate your license

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/upgrade-conversion-options#converting-an-evaluation-version-to-a-retail-version